# how to group, so that the text # becomes one at the bottom of the paragraph

Tags: notepad++

my problem like this :
.⁣
#jsrzaidulakbar#airnanojsr #promiljsr
The community is here to help you with questions about computer software or computer hardware.Provide details and share research with your question.
#jsrzaidulakbar #airnanojsr #promiljsr

want to turn into :

.⁣
The community is here to help you with questions about computer software or computer hardware.Provide details and share research with your question.
#jsrzaidulakbar #airnanojsr #promiljsr #jsrzaidulakbar#airnanojsr #promiljsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there're no # in the text, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*(#.+)\R((?:(?!#)[\s\S])+#.+)`
- Replace with: `$2 $1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    \h*         # optional horizontal spaces
    (#.+)       # group 1, a "#" and 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
    (           # group 2
        (?:         # non capture group
            (?!#)       # negative lookahead, make we haven't a "#" just after current position
            [\s\S]      # any character
        )+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
        #           # a "#"
        .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    )           # end group
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @RommyIrawan: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: but sorry after I tried, it can't work when the # sign is in the middle of a paragraph

Comment: @RommyIrawan: The first line of my answer says “`Assuming there're no # in the text`”. This works for the example you've given. If you have other test cases, please, edit your question with all of them and expected results.